# How does django's RegexURLPattern __init__ work

Tags: django

I am trying to understand the inner workings of the django framework.  Specifically, how URL requests and views function. I'm stuck in understanding how the **init** method in the RegexURLPattern class works. I'm a beginner with Python as well as django, and I'm not sure what to call this behavior in order to Google it. I'm using the pycharm debugger to step through the code as the django server is starting up and initializing it.From what I understand the initialization process is as follows.

Step 1: To begin the process of initializing the URL pattern the as_view class method is first initialized, it returns the view function

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='passreset/pmp_password_reset_confirm.html',
        ), name='password_reset_confirm')
```

Step 2: In django.conf.urls **init** this function receives the url, regex, reference to the view function from step 1 and possibly other arguments

```
def url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None):
    if isinstance(view, (list, tuple)):
        # For include(...) processing.
        urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = view
        return RegexURLResolver(regex, urlconf_module, kwargs, app_name=app_name, namespace=namespace)
    elif callable(view):
        return RegexURLPattern(regex, view, kwargs, name)
    else:
        raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
```

Step 3 In the elif block above a RegexURLPattern object is instantiated. Hitting F7 on the debugger and diving into the object as it is being instantiated drops me into this init block

```
class RegexURLPattern(LocaleRegexProvider):
    def __init__(self, regex, callback, default_args=None, name=None):
        LocaleRegexProvider.__init__(self, regex)
        self.callback = callback  # the view
        self.default_args = default_args or {}
        self.name = name
```

Step 4 and Question 1 : Expanding the properties of self in the debugger I do not see a "callback" attribute, nor is it located int he LocaleRegexProvider mixin. In fact default_args, and name are also not prsent. Only a "lookup_str" and "regex" string property are present. Where does it come from? Does this call create it?

```
self = {RegexURLPattern} Unable to get repr for <class ...
 lookup_str = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File 
 regex = {str} 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
```

Step 5 As i step through the init block and execute self.callback the lookup_str property is magically updated with the string name of the associated view class and a new regex object is added to Self

```
lookup_str = {str} 'django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView'
regex = {SRE_Pattern} re.compile('^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?
```

Step 6 and Question 2: What about self.callback = callback makes the changes described in step 5 possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objects in Python are dynamic. There is nothing specific about the URL pattern classes here. The reason why you don't see the callback property when you enumerate the properties of the class at the start of the `__init__` method is that it simply hasn't been defined yet: as you can see, that definition happens at the end of the method. If you stepped through to the end and enumerated the properties again, you would see that attribute.

The reason that `lookup_str` fails with an exception at first is that it is a `property` rather than an attribute; the underlying method relies on the existence of `self.callback` which again doesn't exist until the end of `__init__`.

Comment: I come from a Java background, the dynmaic nature of Python keeps throwing me off.